# How to disable mouse wheel scroll tapping in debugmode

Tags: listview, flutter, scroll, mousewheel

I used ListView when making Flutter app. But when running it through the emiulator, there is a problem. When scrolling with the mouse wheel, the List View items are taped. Can't sroll. and Scrolling no smooth.

Part of main.dart file

```
    body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          image_Carousel,
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Categories'),
          ),

          //Horizontal ListView Begin Here
          HorizontalList(),
          Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 8.0),
            child: Text('Recent Products'),
          ),

//          Grid view
          Container(
            height: 320.0,
            child: Products(),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Parts of code products.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// my own imports
import 'package:ecommercetuto/pages/product_details.dart';

class Products extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductsState createState() => _ProductsState();
}

class _ProductsState extends State<Products> {
  var product_list = [
    {
      "name": "Blazer",
      "picture": "images/products/blazer1.jpeg",
      "old_price": 120,
      "price": 100,
    },
    {
      "name": "Red Dress",
      "picture": "images/products/dress2.jpeg",
      "old_price": 110,
      "price": 80,
    },
    {
      "name": "Blazer",
      "picture": "images/products/dress1.jpeg",
      "old_price": 150,
      "price": 110,
    },
```

How to Slove this?

Comment: Why do you want to scroll with the mousewheel, just press and drag. On a real device there is no mousewherl so you don't ned to implement this. What excatly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Manuel I just need the mouse wheel, the app is devolop
Just for the time being. The habit is to rotate the mouse wheel. Usually the computer scrolls through the mouse wheel.

Comment: Did you find an answer on this, having the same problem